# programmatically create tracking markers and set per frame coords?

Tags: python, tracking, movie-clip-editor

I would like to import a series of coordinates for multiple "points" for multiple frames but I can't find examples.

I saw how I can add markers with `bpy.ops.clip.add_marker`, but I don't understand how to change coordinates over time, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Found [`MovieTrackingMarkers.insert_frame`](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.81a/bpy.types.MovieTrackingMarkers.html#bpy.types.MovieTrackingMarkers.insert_frame)

```py
clip = bpy.data.movieclips[0]
width = clip.size[0] # 848
height = clip.size[1] # 480
bpy.ops.clip.add_marker(location=(424.0/width,240.0/height))
bpy.data.movieclips[0].tracking.tracks.active.name="test"
clip.tracking.objects[0].tracks[0].markers.insert_frame(10, co=(212.0/width,120.0/height))
clip.tracking.objects[0].tracks[0].markers.insert_frame(20, co=(106.0/width,110.0/height))
clip.tracking.objects[0].tracks[0].markers.insert_frame(30, co=(53.0/width,55.0/height))
```

Well, that was fun:
[use dlib and opencv to track face landmarks](https://gist.github.com/xenogenesi/fc4ec4ecebec4861db87ff633dea6347)